# How to test that akka actor message was sent to it's child

Tags: java, akka

I have ParentActor and ChildActor as follows:

```
class ParentActor extends UntypedActor {
    final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem");

    final ActorRef child = system.actorOf(Props.create(ChildActor.class), "child")

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            getContext().watch(child)
            child.tell(message, getSelf())
        } else {
            unhandled(message)
        }
    }
}

class ChildActor extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            context().parent().tell("Hello from child actor!", self());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test the relationship between parent and child (If I send String message to ParentActor assure that child has got it) using TestKit and in java. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Your “child” is not actually a child Actor, you need to use `getContext().actorOf()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent - inject `Child` actor `Props` via constructor. And change your `Child` - inject parent reference via constructor. In test when creating `Parent` inject another `Child` `Props` which accepts test actor as a parameter. Change:

```
context().parent().tell("Hello from child actor!", self());
```

to

```
parentField.tell("Hello from child actor!", self());
```

Then in your test use akka test actor instead of `Parent` and pass it to Child. And you can check response via `expectMsgEquals` method.

Comment: I've never tried akka with java, only with scala, that's why I've just described the solution.